VW Golf GTI Mk1 1982 DX Heavy Jerks
Here is my problem.
The engine starts normally, but when I'm driving, starts do heavy jerks (shakes). It doesn't matter in which gear. The point is that it only happens when it is moving, but if I'm in neutral or pressing the clutch, the rpm goes up normally. Maybe not 100% smooth, but without any jerks.
I've already changed.

Sparks
Distributor cap
Fuel filter
Distribuitor rotor.
Distribuitor
Coil
Sparks wires
Exterior Fuel Pump

What's happening?
Thank you!

Have you already checked for issues like broken cables, intermittent short to ground or the ignition switch going bad?
